# 2k rows update is very slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 tables:
 1. news (450k rows)
 2. news_tags (3m rows)

There are some triggers on news table update which updating listings. This SQL executes too long...

```
UPDATE news
SET news_category = some_number
WHERE news_id IN (SELECT news_id
                  FROM news_tags
                  WHERE tag_id = some_number); #about 3k rows
```

How can I make it faster?

Thanks in advance,
S.

Comment: Define "slow" please. What is too long? How does the execution plan look? Problems finding the data to update (tag_id not indexed), or problems in the execution thanks to possibly dead slow triggers? Are you CPU or IO bound?

Comment: This is one time update on a production db and it takes more than 5 minutes. Our web application returns 504 error during query execution...

SELECT news_id FROM news WHERE news_id IN (SELECT news_id FROM news_tags WHERE tag_id = some_number) takes 1.04 seconds. So the problem is in triggers but I can't disable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one time update, you may find it better to disable your triggers, run the update, then run a statement that performs what your triggers do in bulk.

Comment: Hi Robin,
Yes, this is one time update BUT I have to update production db. So it's impossible to disable triggers...

Comment: If you disable triggers, run your update, then enable triggers all within a transaction then the table will be locked and no other queries will be allowed to run. This assumes it then runs fast enough for this to be possible.